# gstreamer 1.0 videoscale to capsfilter to d3dvideosink

Tags: sdk, gstreamer

I am trying to change the video format in a rtspsrc. I have fakesink all the way til i got to capsfilter in my program C. It says internal data flow error. anyone know how to get this work?

```
pipel.source = gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc","source");
g_object_set(GST_OBJECT(pipel.source),"location",url,NULL);
pipel.rtppay = gst_element_factory_make( "rtph264depay", "depayl");
pipel.decodebin = gst_element_factory_make ("openh264dec","decode");
pipel.parse = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse","parse");
pipel.videoscale = gst_element_factory_make("videoscale","scale");

filtercaps = gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw,width=320,height=240");
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pipel.filter1), "caps",filtercaps,NULL);
    gst_caps_unref(filtercaps);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipel.pipeline),pipel.source,pipel.rtppay,pipel.parse,pipel.decodebin,pipel.videoscale,pipel.filter1,pipel.sink
                                            ,NULL);
    if(!gst_element_link_many(pipel.rtppay,pipel.parse,pipel.decodebin,pipel.videoscale,pipel.filter1,pipel.sink))
        printf("\nFailed Linking\n");

    g_signal_connect(pipel.source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(cb_new_rtspsrc_pad),pipel.rtppay);
    g_signal_connect(pipel.rtppay, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), pipel.parse);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filtercaps = gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw,width=320,height=240");
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipel.pipeline),pipel.source,pipel.rtppay,pipel.parse,pipel.decodebin,pipel.videoscale,pipel.sink
                                        ,NULL);
if(!gst_element_link_many(pipel.rtppay,pipel.parse,pipel.decodebin,pipel.videoscale,pipel.sink))
    printf("\nFailed Linking\n");
```

adding this line will make it work. You don't use capsfilter in between videoscale and videosink in the bin and the linking.

```
gst_element_link_filtered(pipel.videoscale, pipel.sink, filtercaps);
gst_caps_unref(filtercaps);
```